# Usefulness of Cauchy sequences

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, soft-question, cauchy-sequences

I took two courses in single- and multivariable calculus. Both of which dealt with Cauchy sequences. My question is now, why is the property of being a Cauchy sequence useful? I know that it is used to define complete (metric) spaces, but is there any way in which these sequences are used?

Comment: What do you mean by used? Do you mean used as in mathematics, or used as in applied mathematics , or perhaps used in engineering and technical applications? Assuming you are talking about mathematics, then one reason they are useful is that they have nice convergence properties for first

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cauchy sequences have several important applications:

- Since the Cauchy sequences in a metric space admit a natural equivalence relation (namely $d(x_n,\,y_n)\to0$, with $d$ the space's metric), the equivalence classes provide a metric-completion of the original space. If a metric space is metric-complete, its Cauchy sequences converge; otherwise, we can only guarantee the converse. For example, Cauchy sequences in $\Bbb Q$ need not converge to some limit in $\Bbb Q$, but they *will* have a limit in its metric completion $\Bbb R$, as will all Cauchy sequences in $\Bbb R$ itself. @JoséCarlosSantos already discussed why metric completeness is useful when it occurs. Better still, if you change the norm used to define Cauchy sequences, you get a different metric completion (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ostrowski%27s_theorem) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number)).
- Metric completion also holds in [Banach spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_space) and [Hilbert spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_space), important classes of vector space that allow us to add infinitely many vectors (as long as the partial sums comprise a Cauchy sequence). Whereas the [usual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_(linear_algebra)) definition of a basis, named for Hamel, requires finite linear combinations thereof to span the space, in the above special cases we can instead use a [Schauder basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schauder_basis), for which countably infinite combinations are legal. There's even an uncountable variant, using integrals. These are both vital for the Hilbert spaces used in quantum mechanics.
- On a related note, important theorems on such spaces may be proved with Cauchy sequences, such as the [Banach fixed-point theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem#Proof).

Answer (score 7):

It is useful because it allows us to prove that a sequence converges even without knowing what its limit is.

Consider, for instance, the statement “Every absolutely convergent series converges.” This is proved by proving that, given an absolutely convergent series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$, the sequence $\left(\sum_{n=0}^Na_n\right)_{N\in\mathbb Z_+}$ is a Cauchy sequence. And so we do not have to know what is its sum in order to prove that it converges.

Comment: just to add a bit of jargon: Convergence is a property of a sequence. Every sequence either converges or it does not. Showing that a sequence converges by exhibiting its limit requires information *external* to the sequence, namely the limit $L$. The Cauchy condition, by contrast, is *intrinsic* to the sequence; it does not require any further information that what is already provided.